# Rails: Single Table Inheritance - Subclass model with specific attribute

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, rails-activerecord, single-table-inheritance

Lets say I have a model named `Animal` with attribute `species`.

I intend to subclass `Tiger` from `Animal`, which attribute `species` is "tiger", how to define it so that

`Animal.where(:species => 'tiger').where(:age => 12)`

can be written as

`Tiger.where(:age => 12)`?

My attempted solution:

```
class Tiger < Animal    
  def self.inherited(child)
    child.instance_eval do
      def type
        "tiger"
      end
    end
    super
  end
end
```

References:
 1. http://eewang.github.io/blog/2013/03/12/how-and-when-to-use-single-table-inheritance-in-rails/
 2. http://www.alexreisner.com/code/single-table-inheritance-in-rails

Comment: in parent modal did you tried update inheritence column like this `self.inheritance_column = 'species' `

Answer (score 0):

Whereas I have understand your problem you just want to implement simple STI.

I have tried it and it worked for me. Create a base class Animal in which 
Animal table attributes will be **species**, **name** and **age**.

```
class Animal < ApplicationRecord
  self.inheritance_column = :species

  def self.species
    %w(Lion Tiger)
  end
end
```

Inherited classes.

```
class Lion < Animal
end
class Tiger < Animal
end
```

Try this hope it will solve your problem.

Comment: The species column is in format of small letter, i.e. the subclass Tiger is being identified as Animal with species "tiger" (small letter t). What is the way to specify that?

Comment: As per the convention this isn't possible as they are classes and they can be denoted as Tiger and Lion rather than tiger and lion. but still they will be saved as "Lion" and "Tiger" fetch that and then you can turn it "tiger"

Comment: Is there configuration (over convention) way of doing this? Because existing data were "tiger" in small case and I don't want to change that.

Comment: If you want to store the inherited model name to be stored in lowercase follow this link https://gist.github.com/sumskyi/1381880